# R How to separate a string based white spaces but keeping the decimal dot?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

Could you please help me to separate a string column into 7 columns by keeping the decimal numbers?

Here is one example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

x <- data.frame(Flat = c("2000M01  XZ ELDL U K EER 213.9", "2000M02  XY MLML O T RRE 255.6" , "2000M03  UY LEEE M P SSE 259.4" ))  
x %>% separate(Flat, c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","Value")
```

The output is:

```
     A1   B2  C3   D4 E5 F6 Value
1 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER   213
2 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE   255
3 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE   259
Warning message:
Expected 7 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 3 rows [1, 2, 3].
```

instead of the desired output:

```
   A1     B2 C3    D4 E5 F6   Value
1 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER   213.9
2 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE   255.6
3 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE   259.4
```

I tried many `"sep = "` options in the separate function, but nothing helps.

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `sep` argument as whitespace in `separate`. Also use `convert = TRUE` to change the `Value` column to numeric automatically.

```
tidyr::separate(x, Flat, 
      c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","Value"), sep = '\\s+', convert = TRUE)

#       A1 B2   C3 D4 E5  F6 Value
#1 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER 213.9
#2 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE 255.6
#3 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE 259.4
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this in `base R`  with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = x$Flat, header = FALSE,
       col.names =c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","Value"))
       A1 B2   C3 D4 E5  F6 Value
1 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER 213.9
2 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE 255.6
3 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE 259.4
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not so brilliant as dear @akrun's, but it will also do the trick:

```
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  extract(Flat, c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","Value"), 
          "(\\d+M\\d+)  ([[:upper:]]+) ([[:upper:]]+) ([[:upper:]]) ([[:upper:]]+) ([[:upper:]]+) (\\d+\\.\\d)")

       A1 B2   C3 D4 E5  F6 Value
1 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER 213.9
2 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE 255.6
3 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE 259.4
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option with `tstrsplit`

```
type.convert(
    setDT(x)[, setNames(
        tstrsplit(Flat, "\\s+"),
        c("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5", "F6", "Value")
    )],
    as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
        A1 B2   C3 D4 E5  F6 Value
1: 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER 213.9
2: 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE 255.6
3: 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE 259.4
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` way

```
library(data.table)
ans <- data.table()[,c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","Value") := tstrsplit(x$Flat, "[ ]+")]
#         A1 B2   C3 D4 E5  F6 Value
# 1: 2000M01 XZ ELDL  U  K EER 213.9
# 2: 2000M02 XY MLML  O  T RRE 255.6
# 3: 2000M03 UY LEEE  M  P SSE 259.4
```